How can I make my simple PowerPoint Add-In available to other people?
A friend asked me to develop a simple PowerPoint (365) Add-In since they couldn't find a suitable one in the Office Store.
I opted to create a Web Add-In in Visual Studio, which is working fine when I launch it via F5.
But now I'm stumped as to how to actually ship it to them.
From what I gather, the two main ways to publish are either a company internal sharepoint or publishing to AppSource, which seemingly is reserved for actual businesses.
I've hosted the html on a github page and put it in the manifest, supposedly other people are now able to add my manifest xml to their powerpoint, but I cannot for the live of me find any options for that.
Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

As long as users have access to download your add-in's manifest, they can install the add-in using the "Upload My Add-in" option. This option is available through Office on the web. For guidance, see Manually sideload an add-in to Office on the web. Once the add-in is installed in Office on the web, it should be available to use on other supported platforms, such as Office on Windows.

If you only need the add-in to work on Mac+Windows but not the iOS/Android/Web versions of PowerPoint, you might consider rewriting your add-in in VBA. Far simpler to distribute as a PowerPoint PPAM add-in than the methods you're looking at.

I'd have to see if it's possible for them to switch to Office on the Web, but it's unlikely.
The VBA add-on might also be an option.
